# How do I pass parameter as Date in vb.net web?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a mail webform where I have to show the user only (-1) one day behind messages, so how do pass (yesterday)date as parameter and retrieve the only records of one day back ?
This query is for 'ALL' messages, but I need to filter (yesterday) one day back messages and add a hyperlink or add in a dropdown ?

```
select MSG_SRNO,MSG_SUBJECT,MSG_ID,MSG_CHKD,
   DOF_SENT,DOF_SEEN from  MESSAGES_MAILBOX where  USER=1234
```

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to execute SQL?  Also, what database are you running against (sql server, oracle, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql, try

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE());
```

Comment: can i use this as a SQL statement ?

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1); 

string query = string.Format("select MSG_SRNO,MSG_SUBJECT,MSG_ID,MSG_CHKD,DOF_SENT,DOF_SEEN from  MESSAGES_MAILBOX where DATEPART(year,DOF_SENT) = {0} AND DATEPART(month,DOF_SENT) = {1} AND DATEPART(day,DOF_SENT) = {2}",yesterday.Year,yesterday.Month, yesterday.Day);
```

Comment: @alejandrobog: This is what SqlCommand + Parameters are for.  You really shouldn't advocate straight string manipulation to create sql queries.  This leads to applications that are vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Since I have no context of the app this is just to illustrate the query. Also there no risk of sql injection in this sample, the parameter doesnt come from a user input.

Comment: @ahmed the previous query select all messages from yesterday by comparing the year,month and day to yesterday.

Comment: Thankyou all for your comments and help. I will give a try and let you know.